# How to play iTunes Store Purchased DRM videos in iphone app?

Tags: iphone, video-streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller, drm, movies

Does anyone know how to play the iTunes-Purchased content(Movies/TvShows) in our app.
I tried with below code, but I am getting mediaUrl as nil for videos(Movies/TvShows).

```
    .......

    NSNumber *videoTypeNum = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:MPMediaTypeAnyVideo];
    MPMediaPropertyPredicate *videoPredicate = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:videoTypeNum forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyMediaType];
    MPMediaQuery *videoQuery = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];
    [videoQuery addFilterPredicate: videoPredicate];
    NSArray *items = [videoQuery items];

    for (MPMediaItem *mediaItem in items)  
    {

        NSURL *mediaUrl = (NSUrl *)[mediaItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
    }

    ......
```

Can anyone help me on this?