# Is it possible to apply a realtime filter to videos from the iTunes store on iOS?

Tags: ios, ipad, video-processing, itunes-store

So, as background, I'm looking at creating an app that will be useful for children with lazy eye.  This would be used at the point of treatment when the person can see out of one eye at a time, but needs to practice coordinating the motion of both (useful for 3d vision, etc).

The idea is that the child wears colored 3d (anaglyph) glasses, and you can control what is seen by one eye or the other by color-filtering the content.  As therapy, a child would watch maybe 20 minutes of filtered video a day, which is a fairly easy way of convincing their brain that they need both eyes working together at the same time.  I've got a version running on desktop machines where half the video is visible by each eye, with a small central strip that can be seen by both to make it easier to sync them.

I'm thinking about porting this to iOS.  The biggest question for me is how to get the content onto the device and filtered.

It would be ideal if the users could buy videos they like from the iTunes store, then just pick which video to play in the app, and play it filtered for anaglyph glasses.  Is it possible to apply realtime filters to videos from the iTunes store on iOS?  The closest question to mine that I could find was [How to play iTunes Store Purchased DRM videos in iphone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463618/) , which has no answers.

I'm not so worried about the performance as I am about being able to access the videos from the store (I could always do offline filtering of selected videos).  It seems like apple might not allow this, as it would be a simple way to strip DRM.  But, since this is a rather niche app, I can work with optometrists and get the hardware set up however will work.  While it would be nice, I don't *need* to distribute the app through the app store, so using a jailbroken iPad or private APIs is also an option.

My question is whether there is any way at all to have users purchase videos (TV shows usually) from the iTunes store, and then in the app access the frames programmatically for basic filtering, using official APIs, private APIs, or a jailbroken iPad if necessary.

Comment: If you can feed them into AVAssetReader somehow, my framework can take care of the live filtering for you: https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage . I'm not sure if the iTunes DRM plays well with AVAssetReader, though.

Comment: Most videos purchased on iTunes are DRMed and do not work with AVAssetReader.